# Xcode6 retain]: message sent to deallocated instance gotten

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, xcode6

I have a strange issue when I update to Xcode6.

Here is the scenario:

1. tableviewController is the main entry, when click on each row of the table, it will open an tabbar controller to show different details(4-5 tabbar viewcontrollers). I use navigation controller to show and return between tableview and tabbar showing code:

`UITabBarController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:NO];  //in didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Tabbar controller is defined in storyboard. And resigning from tabbar view  `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

2. All tabbar controller has a base class, sharing common function and menu handler. Before resigning the tabbar, I released all my resource and remove all notification register in each of tabbar controller
3. The problem is when this line is called

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

It shows `[mytabbarController1 retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f83e9af4c80`

4. From the error, it seems an memory management problem, so I add more debugs in dealloc of each tabbar controller, I can see all the dealloc function are called, then after many times [UIViewController _traitCollectionForChildEnvironment:], it stops at zobmie [UITabBarController viewControllers]. This can be seen in instrument->zombie error stack, sorry, I can't post images currently because of my low reputation, so I copy part of its output.
5. I try to hold the UITabBarController *svc with strong for a bit longer in my main entry tableviewcontroller, it will not crash as long as I hold the pointer(Although in my tabbar controller, it already quitted the screen with navigationController popViewControllerAnimated). Then when I set it to nil and want to create a new one to show anther one's details, it crashs immediately.
6. This is a ARC problem since when I change one of my tabbar viewcontroller with MRC, it will not have the problem, but the others,still using ARC, will have the same crash: `[mytabbarcontroller2 retain]: message sent to deallocated instance`

This works fine on Xcode5, it is only existed when I update my xcode to 6 recently. Are there any methods I can trace to the root cause?

Here is the storyboard captured image:

[image]

And zombie capture:

[image: And zombie capture]

Comment: To help visualize the flow, can you post a zoomed out screenshot of your storyboard? You may need to upload it somewhere and post a link as a new user.

Comment: Thanks, Acey, I've added the screenshot as links.

Comment: There is apparently a change in the latest Xcode in that ARC is being a bit more aggressive about collecting "unused" objects.  I suspect that cases where an autoreleased object might have "lived" longer due to never getting back to the thread dispatcher are now being collected earlier, exposing bugs in the way the objects are referenced by other code.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks, but is there any idea we can try to figure it out? It is not my memory management problem, I just can't understand why after the dealloc, retain message can still send to the pointer. In my code, I resign all actions before calling dealloc.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue without converting to MRC, if so can you pelase help me ouy, i've facing the same problem